# Not able to redirect to the current record

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a custom button and onclicking that it will redirect to a vf page. In that i am having 2 custom button "Save" and "Cancel". If i click on Cancel it is redirecting to the current record detail page. But when i click on save the same page is getting refreshed. Here is my code

```
public class Rfleet_AdditionalServices_CLS {

public String strCurrentRecId{get;set;}
public String strOrderId{get;set;}
public String strOptionVal {get;set;}
public String strCarsetOption{get;set;}
public string strNWservice{get;set;}
public string strCBservice{get;set;}
public string strOtherservice{get;set;}
public string strContreOption{get;set;}
public boolean boolShowSave {get;set;}
public List<Service__c> lstService ;
Map<String, Service__c> mapUniqueService ;
public List<Rfleet_Car_Set__c> lstCarset=new List<Rfleet_Car_Set__c>();

public Rfleet_AdditionalServices_CLS(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    strCurrentRecId= apexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('carSetID');
    strOrderId=apexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('orderID');
    boolShowSave =false;
}

public List<SelectOption> getOptions() {

    List<SelectOption> lstOptions  = new List<SelectOption>();
    lstCarset=[select name from Rfleet_Car_Set__c where Order__c=:strOrderId];
    lstOptions .add(new SelectOption('','--None--'));
    for(Rfleet_Car_Set__c strC2Goptions:lstCarset) {
        if(strC2Goptions.id!=strCurrentRecId)
        lstOptions .add(new SelectOption(strC2Goptions.id,strC2Goptions.name));
    }

    return lstOptions ;
}



  public pagereference  retrieveService() {

    system.debug('Selected Values >>>>'+strCarsetOption+strNWservice+strCBservice+strOtherservice+strContreOption);
    system.debug('Value of ID' + strCurrentRecId);
    lstService =new  List<Service__c>();
    boolShowSave =false;
    if(strCarsetOption!=null &&(strNWservice=='true'||strCBservice=='true'||strOtherservice=='true'||strContreOption=='true') ) {
        boolShowSave =true;
    }


    if(strNWservice=='true') {

        List<Service__c> lstSNWService=[SELECT id,Displayed_Code_Label__c,Name,Service_Type__c,Simple_service_type__c,Simple_Product__c,Code__c,Label__c,Rfleet_VAT_Rate__c,Rfleet_TTC_Amount__c,Car_Set__c,Price_HT__c,Customer_Sales_Price_HT__c,Quantity__c,Simple_Product__r.Rfleet_Active_Service__c from Service__c where Service_Type__c='Simple product' and Simple_service_type__c='Network' and Car_Set__c=:strCarsetOption];
        List<Service__c> lstCNWService=[select id,name,Displayed_Code_Label__c,Car_Set__c from Service__c where Service_Type__c='Simple product' and Simple_service_type__c='Network' and Car_Set__c=:strCurrentRecId];
        lstService =getUniqueRecords(lstCNWService,lstSNWService);
        system.debug('SelectedlstService 11>>>>'+lstService );


    } 

    if(strCBservice=='true') {

        List<Service__c> lstSCBService=[select id,name,Displayed_Code_Label__c,Service_Type__c,Rfleet_CB_Account__c,CB_Options_repository__c,CB_Services_Repository__c,Code__c,Label__c,Rfleet_VAT_Rate__c,Rfleet_TTC_Amount__c,Price_HT__c,Customer_Sales_Price_HT__c,Quantity__c from Service__c where Service_Type__c='Coach-Builder' and Car_Set__c=:strCarsetOption];
        List<Service__c> lstCCBService=[select id,name,Displayed_Code_Label__c from Service__c where Service_Type__c='Coach-Builder' and Car_Set__c=:strCurrentRecId];
        lstService =getUniqueRecords(lstCCBService,lstSCBService);
        system.debug('SelectedlstService 22>>>>'+lstService );


    }


    if(strContreOption=='true') {

        List<Service__c> lstSContreOption=[SELECT id,Displayed_Code_Label__c,Name,Service_Type__c,Simple_service_type__c,Simple_Product__c,Code__c,Label__c,Rfleet_VAT_Rate__c,Rfleet_TTC_Amount__c,Car_Set__c,Price_HT__c,Customer_Sales_Price_HT__c,Quantity__c,Simple_Product__r.Rfleet_Active_Service__c from Service__c where Service_Type__c='Simple product' and Simple_service_type__c='Contremarque Option' and Car_Set__c=:strCarsetOption];
        List<Service__c> lstCContreOption=[select id,name,Displayed_Code_Label__c,Car_Set__c from Service__c where Service_Type__c='Simple product' and Simple_service_type__c='Contremarque Option' and Car_Set__c=:strCurrentRecId];
        lstService =getUniqueRecords(lstCContreOption,lstSContreOption);
        system.debug('SelectedlstService 33>>>>'+lstService );


    }

    if(strOtherservice=='true') {

        List<Service__c> lstSOthrService=[SELECT id,Displayed_Code_Label__c,Name,Service_Type__c,Simple_service_type__c,Simple_Product__c,Code__c,Label__c,Rfleet_VAT_Rate__c,Rfleet_TTC_Amount__c,Car_Set__c,Price_HT__c,Customer_Sales_Price_HT__c,Quantity__c,Simple_Product__r.Rfleet_Active_Service__c from Service__c where Service_Type__c='Simple product' and Simple_service_type__c='Other' and Car_Set__c=:strCarsetOption];
        List<Service__c> lstCOthrService=[select id,name,Displayed_Code_Label__c,Car_Set__c from Service__c where Service_Type__c='Simple product' and Simple_service_type__c='Other' and Car_Set__c=:strCurrentRecId];
        lstService =getUniqueRecords(lstCOthrService,lstSOthrService);
        system.debug('SelectedlstService 44>>>>'+lstService );


    }
    try {
            if(lstService.size()>0) {
                insert lstService;                  
            }
           // return new Pagereference ('/'+strCurrentRecId);
        } catch( Exception ex) {
          //  return null; 

          }
          return new Pagereference('/'+strCurrentRecId);
} 



public Pagereference cancel() {


return new Pagereference ('/'+strCurrentRecId);


}

public List<Service__c>  getUniqueRecords(List<service__c> lstCurrentRecord,List<service__c> lstSelectedRecord ) {

    system.debug('lstCurrentRecord<<<<'+lstCurrentRecord);
    system.debug('lstSelectedRecord <<<<'+lstSelectedRecord );
    mapUniqueService = new map<String, Service__c>();
    List<Service__c> lstServiceAdd=new  List<Service__c>();
    if(lstCurrentRecord.size()>0) {   
        for(Service__c objService: lstCurrentRecord) {
            mapUniqueService.put(objService.Displayed_Code_Label__c,objService); 
        }
    }  
    system.debug('<<<<mapUniqueService'+mapUniqueService);
    if(lstSelectedRecord .size()>0) {
        for(Service__c sObjService: lstSelectedRecord ) {
            system.debug('selObjService<<<'+sObjService);   
               if(!mapUniqueService.containsKey(sObjService.Displayed_Code_Label__c )&& mapUniqueService.size()>0 ) {

                Service__c serv=new Service__c();
                serv = sObjService.clone();
                serv.Car_Set__c=strCurrentRecId;
                if(serv.Simple_Product__r.Rfleet_Active_Service__c==true&&serv.Simple_Product__c!=null) { lstServiceAdd.add(serv); }
                else if(serv.Simple_Product__c==null){lstServiceAdd.add(serv); }
                system.debug('<<<<If lstServiceAdd<<'+lstServiceAdd);

            } else if(mapUniqueService.size()==0){

                Service__c serv=new Service__c();
                serv = sObjService.clone();
                serv.Car_Set__c=strCurrentRecId;

                if(serv.Simple_Product__r.Rfleet_Active_Service__c==true&&serv.Simple_Product__c!=null) { lstServiceAdd.add(serv); }
                else if(serv.Service_Type__c=='Simple product'&& serv.Simple_Product__r.Rfleet_Active_Service__c==true&&serv.Simple_Product__c!=null) { lstServiceAdd.add(serv); }
                else if(serv.Simple_Product__c==null){lstServiceAdd.add(serv); }
                system.debug('<<<<Else lstServiceAdd<<'+lstServiceAdd);
            }       
        }
    }
    return lstServiceAdd;
}

}
```

VF page Code :

```
<apex:page standardController="Rfleet_Car_Set__c" extensions="Rfleet_AdditionalServices_CLS" >
<apex:form >

<apex:pageBlock >

 <apex:pageblockbuttons location="bottom" >
 <apex:outputPanel id="sService">
    <apex:commandbutton value="Save" action="{!retrieveService}" rendered="{!boolShowSave}"/> 
     <apex:commandbutton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}" />
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:pageblockbuttons>


<apex:pageblocksection columns="1" >

    <apex:pageblocksectionitem >
    <apex:outputLabel >Carset</apex:outputLabel>
    <apex:selectList size="1"  value="{!strCarsetOption}" >
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Options }" > </apex:selectOptions>
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!retrieveService}" reRender="a"/>
    </apex:selectList> 
    </apex:pageblocksectionitem>

    <apex:pageblocksectionitem >
     <apex:outputLabel > Network services</apex:outputLabel>
     <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!strNWservice}"> <apex:actionsupport event="onclick" action="{!retrieveService}" reRender="ch1,sService"/>
     </apex:inputCheckbox>
    </apex:pageblocksectionitem>

    <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
    <apex:outputLabel >Coach-Builder services</apex:outputLabel>
    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!strCBservice}"> <apex:actionsupport event="onclick" action="{!retrieveService}" reRender="ch2,sService"/>             
    </apex:inputCheckbox>
    </apex:pageblockSectionItem>

    <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
    <apex:outputLabel >Other services</apex:outputLabel>
    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!strOtherservice}">  <apex:actionsupport event="onclick" action="{!retrieveService}" reRender="ch3,sService"/>          
    </apex:inputCheckbox>
    </apex:pageblockSectionItem>

    <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
    <apex:outputLabel >Contremarque options</apex:outputLabel>
    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!strContreOption}">   <apex:actionsupport event="onclick" action="{!retrieveService}" reRender="ch4,sService"/>         
    </apex:inputCheckbox>
    </apex:pageblockSectionItem>



    </apex:pageblocksection>
</apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I highly recommend you to read [VisualForce in practice](https://www.developerforce.com/guides/Visualforce_in_Practice.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardController_methods.htm

If you refer to StandardController Methods:

- cancel()
  Returns the PageReference of the cancel page.
- save()
  Saves changes and returns the updated PageReference.

In your code you're overriding cancel with:

```
public Pagereference Cancel() {
    return new Pagereference ('/'+strCurrentRecId);
}
```

where

```
strCurrentRecId= apexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('carSetID');
```

You will be redirected to specified Id object page detail.

If you want to redirect user after save has been clicked, override it with:

```
public Pagereference Save() {
    //insert/update yourObject;
    return new Pagereference ('/'+yourObjectId);
}
```